# How can I insert/get data from the MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to insert data into a MySQL Database.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('mysql4.000webhost.com', 'a9671143_cas', '08011998', 'a9671143_testdb');
$number = $_POST['number'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$partiesIds = $_POST['partiesIds'];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO User (number, name, password, partiesIds) VALUES (test, test, test, test)');
mysqli_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And I get this:
[image]

What's wrong, I got this code from a tutorial so I don't understand it well.

Comment: Read the errors, they are extremely valuable: "Access denied for user...". This means that the username and / or password you tried to use in your `mysqli_connect` statement are incorrect.  (The subsequent errors are a result of not being connected successfully, so don't yet factor in to the issue).

Comment: It seems there is some issue with username or password from the screenshot. May be there is no password in your localhost. Please check once again.

Comment: @cale_b , But it is right, that's the point. D;

Comment: So it **wasnt** right, was it?  I **did** point you in the correct direction. (At least according to the answer you accepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct this line : `$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`
Your host/name/password or db name is not correct.

Comment: Should it be $con = mysqli_connect('mysql4.000webhost.com', 'a9671143_cas', '08011998', 'a9671143_testdb');? The password is right, I just changed it. So is the user.

Comment: Have you created access from your user to your db?

Comment: What do you mean by access to my db?

Comment: Often when I make a db, I make user than make db. Not directly make user and db in once time. So, when you make your db, is it correct way? If so, test your setting with code like here
`if($con)echo "Success Connect";` //if not showing Success Connect, your setting of DB is wrong